# How to save the state of toggle button android

Tags: android, save, toggle

I need to save the information about the toggle button when the user kill the app or restarted i want to display the previous state of the button Thanks

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ToggleButton toggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar menu = getSupportActionBar();
        menu.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        menu.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        menu.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    enableNotifications();
                } else {
                    makeDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can use shared preference for that

Comment: Android offers a [lot of options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for that. Shared preferences is the way to go for simple storage like this.

Comment: you can use the shared preferences for storing the toggled state of button and refilling it when needed

Comment: I got it working the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899182/how-to-save-togglebutton-state-using-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

Use shared prefernces for the same.

```
togButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                     int notification_status = Integer.parseInt(mPreferences.getString("status", "-1"));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=mPreferences.edit();
                    Log.i("notification_status="+notification_status,"888");
                    if(notification_status==-1){
                          editor.putString("status", "1");
                          holder.notification_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification_on);
                          //do your stuff
                    }else if(notification_status==1){
                        editor.putString("status", "0");
                        holder.notification_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification_off);
                        //do your stuff
                    }else if(notification_status==0){
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        holder.notification_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification_on);
                        //do your stuff
                    }
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences as following class

```
public class YourPreferenes {

    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private static YourPreferenes mYourPreferenes;
    private YourPreferenes(Context ctx){
        mContext = ctx;
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("ATSPreferenes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static ATSPreferenes getInstance(Context ctx){
        if(mYourPreferenes == null){
            mYourPreferenes = new YourPreferenes(ctx);
        }
        return mYourPreferenes;
    }

    public void setButtonState(boolean btnstate){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("btnstate", btnstate);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getButtonState(){
        return mPrefs.getBoolean("btnstate", false);
    }
}


And get your saved togalbutton stat even you kill your app.
```