# Android - ImageButton Loses Pressed State When New Activity Launched

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` which changes depending on whether it is in a pressed state or not. This is working fine, until I launch a new activity.

When an object from the `ListView` is clicked it starts a new activity, but just before the new activity launches in to the foreground I can see the `ImageButton` going back to it's default state.

When I press the back button to go back to my `MainActivity`, the `ImageButton` is in it's default state but I want it to remain in the state that it is in when the `ListView` is clicked to launch the new activity.

So in this scenario I would have wanted it to remain in it's pressed state through launching the new activity and then going back to the `MainActivity`.

I'm not sure if this is a default feature which just clears any sort of object states upon launching a new activity or if there is something I am doing incorrectly?

Also if this is default behaviour is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

What I recomend to you is use the shared preferences to save the button state. You can see it in this post:[how to save togglebutton state using shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899182/how-to-save-togglebutton-state-using-shared-preferences)

Comment: If I understand `SharedPreferences` correctly, the values persist even when the user closes the application. However I only require the `ImageButton` to keep it's state for the duration of the application being open. I wouldn't want them to re-open the app to find the button is already in a state of being pressed just because that's where they left it last time.

However I suppose I could add something in `onCreate` to set it back to it's default state to get around that problem. I'll give it a try and see how I get on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the end was a very simple one. In `onPause`, I stored the state of the `ImageButton` in a `Bundle` and then in `onResume` I called the stored state from the `Bundle`.